# Change the PYTHON_PREFIX in configure.ac

Tags: python, automake

I want to change the python prefix

I want to install my files in $(myown_pfx)/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages

Now by default, the pythondir seems to point to $(prefix)/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages

I have the following in my configure.ac

```
 AM_PATH_PYTHON([2.7])
 AC_SUBST([PYTHON_PREFIX], ["$myown_pfx"])
```

However, my expected files are still installed as if the PYTHON_PREFIX never changed to $myown_pfx, it was still the default $prefix.

I basically want to override the PYTHON_PREFIX, but have been unsuccessful, what am i missing?

I have been reading this documentation
https://www.gnu.org/software/automake/manual/html_node/Python.html

Answer (score 0):

Regretfully [AM_PATH_PYTHON](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/automake.git/tree/m4/python.m4?h=v1.15.1#n100) sets it, unconditionally, as follows:

```
AC_SUBST([PYTHON_PREFIX], ['${prefix}'])
```

What can be done (other than recalculating `pythondir` similarly to what `AM_PATH_PYTHON` does) is to replace `'${prefix}'` by `$myown_pfx`:

```
pythondir=`echo "$pythondir" | sed s,'${prefix}',"$myown_pfx",`
```

or maybe better:

```
pythondir=`echo "$pythondir" | sed "s,$PYTHON_PREFIX,$myown_pfx,"`
```